# Unrecognized selector sent to instance for Bar Button

Tags: swift, xcode, twitter

I'm making a Twitter app on Xcode and have encountered a frustrating error.

I'm tryna make the Tweet bar button present modally.

[image: Text]

When I run the code it crashes if I click "Tweet"
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Twitter.TweetViewController _finishDecodingLayoutGuideConnections:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fb1a25512c0'
*** First throw call stack: 
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

```
import UIKit

class TweetViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var tweetTextView: UITextView!

    @IBAction func cancel(_ sender: Any) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


    @IBAction func Tweet(_ sender: Any) {
        if (!tweetTextView.text.isEmpty) {
            TwitterAPICaller.client?.postTweet(tweetString: tweetTextView.text, success:{ self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            }, failure: { (error) in
                print("Error posting tweet \(error)")
                self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                })
            } else {
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

        }
    }
```

I looked up people with similar issues but could not find an solution that helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Verify the `IBOutlets` and `IBActions` are properly connected. These crash happens when the `XIB` and `Class` files are not properly connected.

Try to remove the connections and add it again. Also rename the property names if the error persist.